# Postfix: Allow SMTP AUTH only from specified IP address ranges

Tags: postfix, smtp, authentication, ip-address, smtp-auth

can one implement an **IP address based restriction** for **SMTP AUTH in Postfix**?

Scenario:
I'm running a Postfix mail server that receives mails from all over the Internet. But the server doesn't only receive mails, it also allows its authenticated users to send mails to internal users or to external ones. So far no problem.

Unfortunately, I'm always getting a little scared when reading the log files. There are thousands of unsuccessful, illegal login attempts every day from IP addresses from all over the world.

But actually the legitimate sender hosts only come from a handful of known ip address ranges. So I know **only** someone from (for example)

- 134.500.0.0/16
- 134.700.42.0/24
- 134.800.133.7

**might** even be a legitimate sender at all. (I know that the IP address given in the example above are malformed. I just don't wanted to unveil the real ones.)

So if the sender comes from a different ip range, he's for sure none of my users and therfore not allowed to relay anything.

I don't want someone from outside of these subnets to be able to relay **even** if he figures out a valid username/password combination for SMTP AUTH. If he's from a non-white-listed ip address range, he mustn't send. Under no circumstances. So `permit_sasl_authenticated` alone is not enough. As long as someone from *"certain"* countries (I don't want to name them explicitly...) is able to login with stolen/brute-forced/spyed credentials, it's not secure enough. :-) (Think of social engineering, trojan keyloggers that steal account data, lightheaded users with easy-to-guess passwords, etc.)

=> So is it possible to implement an ip address restriction for SMTP AUTH login attempts?
(The receiving of incoming mails must not be affected by this. For that I have `policyd-weight` etc. Here it's only about outgoing / to be relayed mails.)

Solutions that **won't work**:

- `iptables` firewall restriction. As I want to be able to receive mails from all over the Internet on port 25, I cannot implement restrictions on transport layer level. - Moreover, I want the legitimate users to be able to connect on port 25 to admit new outgoing mails into the server. So allowing mail sending only via a subnet restricted-mystery tcp port, e.g. 24343, is no solution, too.
- `permit_mynetworks`: Not everybody from the known ip ranges is a legitimate user. So I can't allow everybody from there to send. SMTP AUTH login is necessary to determine whether someone is an authorized user.

Answer (score 4):

How about putting your SMTP AUTH on another port like 587, and using iptables to restrict access to that port? 587 isn't a hidden port, it's an RFC defined mail submission port. Mail to you arrives on 25, mail through you needs to go over 587.

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6409

Comment: Hopefully he has _already_ set this up.

Comment: I'm know I'm a bit late, but how do I move smtp auth to another port and disable smtp auth on 25?

Comment: In the `master.cf` you'll find lines defining that http://www.postfix.org/master.5.html the `inet` line is the one you want, this is quite useful also: https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/postfix-the-definitive/0596002122/ch04s05.html

Answer (score 2):

Pretty old question, but if you like me come here from Google - this can be done via [smtpd_discard_ehlo_keyword_address_maps](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_discard_ehlo_keyword_address_maps) feature.

You just add parameter

```
smtpd_discard_ehlo_keyword_address_maps = cidr:/etc/postfix/discard_ehlo_keyword
```

to your Postfix `main.cf` config (usually located at `/etc/postfix/main.cf`) where `/etc/postfix/discard_ehlo_keyword` is a path to Postfix lookup table.

Next let's create a file via e.g. `sudo nano /etc/postfix/discard_ehlo_keyword` and put content inside it:

```
# this is your trusted ip ranges you want to send AUTH:
134.500.0.0/16      silent-discard 
134.700.42.0/24     silent-discard
# and this is another world you don't want to send AUTH to:
0.0.0.0/0           silent-discard, auth 
::/0                silent-discard, auth
```

After save run `sudo postmap /etc/postfix/discard_ehlo_keyword` to generate Postfix lookup table (you should do this after every edit of `/etc/postfix/discard_ehlo_keyword`).

And don't forget to restart Postfix!

Answer (score 1):

You want to use a negated form of [`smtpd_sasl_exceptions_networks`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_sasl_exceptions_networks).

`smtpd_sasl_exceptions_networks = !134.500.0.0/16 !134.700.42.0/24 !134.800.133.7`

You might also be interested in [`smtpd_client_connection_rate_limit`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_client_connection_rate_limit).

Answer (score 0):

I would advice you to use a HIDS like [OSSEC](http://www.ossec.net/) to temporarily block IPs that tried to log in. You can also add a rule in OSSEC to exclude your trusted networks from this rule, so legitimate users don't get blocked after a few attempts.

I'm proposing this as I don't think Postfix actually has a way to complement my_networks and SASL.

Answer (score 0):

> There are thousands of unsuccessful, illegal login attempts every day from IP addresses from all over the world.

install fail2ban and tweak an existing or create a new filter to trap for these.  I use:

```
failregex =\[<HOST>\]\: SASL LOGIN authentication failed
```